# Error: page requested not found codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

**Controller**

```
public function index()
{
    //load session library
    $this->load->library('session');

    if($this->session->userdata('user')){
        // redirect('home');
        $this->load->view('heropage');
    }
    else{
        $this->load->view('login_page');
    }
}
public function login(){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $data = $this->Users_model->login($email, $password);

    if($data)
    {
        $id=$data[0]->id;
        $first_name=$data[0]->firstname;
        $last_name=$data[0]->lastname;
        $grade=$data[0]->grade;
        $points=$data[0]->points;
        $this->session->set_userdata('user_id',$id);
        $this->session->set_userdata('lname',$last_name);
        $this->session->set_userdata('user', $email);
        $this->session->set_userdata('fname',$first_name);
        $this->session->set_userdata('grade',$grade);
        $this->session->set_userdata('pts',$points);
        $this->getImg();
        redirect('home');
    }
    else{
        header('location:'.base_url().$this->index());
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Invalid login. User not found');         }
    }
```

**View**

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['success'])) :?>
<div class="alert alert-success"><?=$_SESSION['success'];?></div>
<?php endif; if(isset($_SESSION['error'])) :?>
<div class="alert alert-warning"><?=$_SESSION['error'];?></div>
    <?php endif;?>
    <!-- End alerts -->
    <form action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/User/login" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Email:</label>
            <input  type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email">
            <?php echo form_error('email'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Password:</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control"name="password" placeholder="Password">
            <?php echo form_error('password'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" type="submit" align="center" name="login" class="submit">Log in</button>
        </div>
</div>
    </form>
```

**model**

```
public function login($email,$password)
{           
    $query = $this->db->get_where('users', array('email'=>$email));
    if($query->num_rows() == 1 )
    {
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

Upon trying to log in, I got the error page cant be found. I want it to go to the home page if the session is correct. here is the error message:

404 Page Not Found
The page you requested was not found.

How can I solve the error because I have also set as needed in the routes

Comment: I think your form `action` should be `<?php echo base_url();?>user/login"`

Answer (score 0):

- I think your form action should be `<?php echo base_url(); ?>user/login`
- Also in your `model` you're not checking for `password` anywhere.
- You're also not returning anything if the email is not found or more than 1 results are found -
  `($query->num_rows() == 1)`

**Model**

```
    public function login($email,$password)
    {

        $query = $this->db->get_where('users', array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password))->result(); // you should use row() here to return only 1 row.

        return $query; // you should check the uniqueness of email on registration, not here -- not allow duplicate email on registration
    }
```

**Controller**

```
public function login(){

    $email    = $_POST['email']; // $this->input->post('email');
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $data = $this->Users_model->login($email, $password);

    if( !empty($data) )  // if no result found it'll be empty
    {
        // your code
    }
    else{
        header('location:'.base_url().$this->index());
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Invalid login. User not found');
    }
}
```

See, if this helps you.